# Create JSON object using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I currently have a Highcharts in my code, I used JavaScript to massage the data by creating JSON object, the code snippet looks like

```
var yearChartOptions = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'YearChartContainer',
        type: 'column',
        margin: [ 50, 50, 50, 50]
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [],
        labels: {
            rotation: -90,
            align: 'right'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        plotLines: [{
            color: '#FF0000',
            width: 2,
            label: {
                style: {
                    color: 'blue',
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    zIndex: -1
                },
                formatter: function () {
                    return '$' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value/1000, 0) +'k ';
                }
            },
            zIndex: 10
        }]
    },
};

// Create the chart
var yearChart = new Highcharts.Chart(yearChartOptions);
```

How can I write in TypeScript to have the same JavaScript result?

Comment: `yearChartOptions` is a JavaScript object. [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: you mean I need to create Highcharts objects by myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `/// <reference path="highcharts.d.ts" />` tag to your file. You can get the file from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/highcharts/highcharts.d.ts). Everything should just work from there.